Why I can't compare two dates using comparison symbols in Excel?
So I have this date on a cell:
E4 = 7/2/2024

On my computer: It doesn't work when I want to compare it with another date.
E6 = E4 > 6/2/2024

Returns FALSE
On Microsoft 365 online: It works without adding anything.
E6 = E4 > 6/2/2024

Returns TRUE
Surely I can use DATE(), but I need it to work without using any functions since I need to put 2 dates on different cells as a range of time inside a criteria to use DSUM().
I've been following a tutorial and this is exactly how they compare dates but it doesn't work on my PC.
I think it's a problem with how Excel is interpreting '6/2/2024' but I don't know how to fix it, I've tried with "" , '' () but nothing works, maybe it has to do with some setting configuration.

=E4>DATEVALUE("6/2/2004")

I need it to work without using any functions

=E4>--"6/2/2004"

Place the date you want to compare to in another cell, and reference to that.

Note that "6/2/2024" (within quotes) is not a date, but a string. Dates are (formatted) numbers.

It is not working because Excel sees that as =E4>0.125 where as you need =E4>--"6/2/24"

Go to "Formulas" at the top of the Application, then click on the "Evaluate Formula" button, and step through slowly.  That will let you know what step it goes wonky at.  That said, =E4 > --"6/2/2024"  should get you the results you want (using only Operators, and no Functions)

Dont change any context of your OP once the answer is accepted

I changed it to how it was before adding the part of Microsoft365 since I noticed it doesn't work on it as well after trying with other dates.

Sorry no offense here, but you removed this line: On Microsoft 365 online: It works without adding anything. not sure how web version works. In web version there are few anomalies, which works there but not in desktop. there are some posts related to here. so let it be. if someone is aware of the issue why it worked for you over web and not in desktop may be will explain.

As BigBen, Mayukh Bhattacharya and Chronocidal
Commented answered, applying "--" to the date should work:

P.S.: "VERDADEIRO" means "TRUE". My Excel is in Portuguese.

Not just double unary, date within quotes and then make the same as a number using double unary. the reason it is not working has already been stated in comments above placing in another cell is only a workaround root cause is different (excel divides each to compare i.e. 6/2/2024 --> E4>0.00148221343873518
